# Eclipse 4 RCP Application (standalone!): Add "show view" in menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my standalone RCP Application (which I start using a product configuration) I would like to add a menu entry "show view" that lists all views I have defined in my persistent application model (an *application.e4xmi* file) being **closed**.
Currently I do not have any *Advisor* Classes in use.

What I did was to manually add *HandledMenuItems* for each view and added a *CoreExpression* as *Visible-When Expression*.

This expression tests for a special key value pair in the *application context*. The problem here is that I would need a special expression for each view.

What would be a good pattern to solve this problem?
Or is there a way to parametrize the core expression?
Could I use any predefined eclipse plugins / commands / handlers?

**Update**: Instead it would also be okay to have the Window > Show View structure in my standalone RCP application - exactly like it exists in the Eclipse workbench. Is there a way to add this menu (entry) by using any predefined / available means?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps you, because it's eclipse 3.7 code, but you can give it a try.

I added a dynamic menu contribution to the *View* menu like so:

```
<menu id="x.y.menu.views label="%menu.window.label">
  <dynamic class="x.y.menu.ViewListMenuContribution" id="viewlist" />
</menu>
```

In that class, I used one of the the eclipse menu factories to actually fill the menu:

```
@Override
public void fill(Menu menu, int index)
{
    super.fill(menu, index);

    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IContributionItem item = ContributionItemFactory.VIEWS_SHORTLIST.create(window);

    if (item != null)
        item.fill(menu, index);
}
```

This should show all views that are currently closed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is definitely worth a try but I read a blog article that this feature is not yet included in the current Eclipse release. So right now I am still looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that, except keeping track of the parts yourself and reopening them with the `EPartService`