# Registering a view in fragment.e4xmi when using Legacye4.xmi

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am trying to create a new view using Eclipse e4 (my product is RCP 3.x based, but now updated to use the Legacye4.xmi, but existing views and perspectives registered via 3.x ext. points). I am currently registering my view using the ext point org.eclipse.ui.views/e4View. I am now trying to register the view in a fragment.e4xmi file.

How do I go about doing this? Various examples on the internet seem to start from a custom application.xmi where the fragment editor can pick the correct element IDs. I have tried registering a "PartDescriptor" under the Application root, but this does not show up in the "Show Views/Other" menu. I have tried adding a "Part" to the application/window. However while this does add the view to the application, there are no window borders, and it still does not show up in the "Show Views/Other" menu.

What is the correct way to register a view to appear in the "Show Views/Other" menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is currently not possible. See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/499424/.

A custom menu handler would appear to be the way  - [Eclipse 4 RCP Application (standalone!): Add "show view" in menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123345/eclipse-4-rcp-application-standalone-add-show-view-in-menu)